# A question to C operations :return 1 when all bits of byte i of x equal 1; 0 otherwise

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

> You are asked to complete the following C function:
>
> ```
> /* Return 1 when all bits of byte i of x equal 1; 0 otherwise. */
> int allBits_ofByte_i(unsigned x, int i) {
>     return _____________________ ;
> }
> ```

My solution: `!!(x&(0xFF << (i<<3)))`

The correct answer to this question is:

```
!~(~0xFF | (x >> (i << 3 ))
```

Can someone explain it?

Also, can someone take a look at my answer, is it right?

Comment: Post your question as text, not as a link to a picture.

Comment: yours I guess returns 1 if *any* bits are set and in the given byte, not all... And the constant should be `0xFFU` to have it as unsigned always...

Comment: recommend breaking it down into different steps. Start with the inner parenthesis, assign that operation to a temp value, and keep expanding out like that. Seeing what each step is doing should make it easier to understand as a whole rather than everything all mashed together on one line, which can get overwhelming. Quite frankly I'd prefer to see that split up over multiple lines. Source code is for human readers, it should be clear as possible what's happening. Certainly some elegance mashing it all into one line, but let the optimizer do that.

Comment: In your solution, what happens if just one bit of the byte is 1 and the others are 0?

Comment: @Sneftel It is done.

Comment: It's a question in two parts. (1) extract the correct byte from an `unsigned` presumably 32 bit integer, and (2) test if every bit is set in an integer type (the exact type doesn't matter for this part).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `!~(~0xFF | (x >> (i << 3 ))` is evaluated as follows.

1. `i<<3` multiplies `i` by 8 to get a number of bits which will be 0, 8, 16, or 24, depending on which byte the caller wants to test. This is actually the number of bits to ignore, as it is the number of bits that are less significant than the byte we're interested it.
2. `(x >> ...)` shifts the test value right to eliminate the low bits that we're not interested in. The 8 bits of interest are now the lowest 8 bits in the `unsigned` value we're evaluating. Note that other higher bits may or may not be set.
3. `(~0xFF | ...)` sets all 24 bits above the 8 we're interested in, but does not alter those 8 bits. (`~0xFF` is a shorthand for `0xFFFFFF00`, and yes, arguably 0xFFu should be used).
4. `~(...)` flips all bits. This will result in a value of zero if every bit was set, and a non-zero value in every other case.
5. `!(...)` logically negates the result. This will result in a value of 1 only if every bit was set during step 3. In other words, every bit in the 8 bits we were interested in was set. (The other 24 bits were set in step 3.)

The algorithm can be summed up as, set the 24 bits we're not interested in, then verify that 32 bits are set.

Your answer took a slightly different approach, which was to shift the `0xFF` mask left rather than shift the test value right. That was my first thought for how to approach the problem too! But your *logical* negation doesn't verify that every bit is set, which is why your answer wouldn't produce correct results in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

`x` is of unsigned integer type. Let's say that `x` is (often) 32 bit.

One byte consists of 8 bits. So `x` has 4 bytes in this case: 0, 1, 2 or 3

According to the solution the endianness of the architecture can be imagined as follows:

```
x => bbbb bbbb  bbbb bbbb  bbbb bbbb  bbbb bbbb
i =>     3          2          1          0
```

I will try to break it down:

```
!~ ( ~0xFF | ( x >> (i << 3) ) )
```

`i` can be either 0, 1, 2 or 3. So `i << 3` would either give you 0, 8, 16 or 24. (`i << n` is like multiplying by `2^n`; it means shift `i` to the left `n` times putting `0`).
Note that 0, 8, 16 and 24 are the byte segments: 0-7, 8-15, 16-23, 24-31
This is used to ...

`x >> (i<<3)` shifts to the right `x` by that result (0, 8, 16 or 24 times). So that the corresponding byte denoted by the `i` parameter occupies now the *right most* bits.
Until now you manipulated `x` so that the byte you are interested in is located on the *right most* 8 bits (the *right most* byte).

~0xFF is the inversion of `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111` which gives you `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0000 0000`

The bitwise or operator is applied to the two results above, which would result in 
`1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 abcd efgh` - the letters being the bits of the corresponding byte of `x`.

`~1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 abcd efgh` will turn into `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 ABCD EFGH` - the capital letters being the inverse of the lower letters' values.

`!0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 ABCD EFGH` is a logical operation. `!n` is 1 if `n` is `0`, and it is 0 if `n` is otherwise.
So you get a 1 if all the inverted bits of the corresponding byte were `0000 0000` (i.e. the byte is `1111 1111`).
Otherwise you get a 0.

In the C programming language a result of 0 corresponds to a boolean false value. And a result different than 0 corresponds to a boolean true value.